# jQuery Datatables align center 1 column

Tags: jquery, html, css, datatables

Want to align center just the first column called "Status":

```
        $("#TransactionTable").DataTable({
            ajax: {
                url: '/Transaction/SearchMockup',
                type: 'POST',
                data: {
                    cardEndingWith: $("#ccn").val(),
                    status: $("#status").val(),
                    supplier: $("#supplier").val(),
                    fromDate: $("#fromDate").val(),
                    toDate: $("#toDate").val()
                }
            },
            columns: [
            {
                data: 'Status', render: function (data, type, row) {
                    switch (data) {
                        case 1:
                            return '<div id="circleRed"></div>'
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            return '<div id="circleGreen"></div>'
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            return '<div id="circleOrange"></div>'
                            break;
                    }
                }
            },
            { data: 'TransactionId' },
            { data: 'CreditCardNumber' },
            { data: 'Supplier' },
            { data: 'CreatedAt' },
            { data: 'Amount' }
            ]
        });
```

What i need to add the columns option to make it happen? I try to read all the Datatables doc and google.

Answer (score 87, accepted):

You can use your theme classes (bootstrap), or your own in columndef.
like

> text-right, text-left, text-center

```
 'columnDefs': [
    {
        "targets": 0, // your case first column
        "className": "text-center",
        "width": "4%"
   },
   {
        "targets": 2,
        "className": "text-right",
   }
 ]
```

Comment: Alternative of @aabiro 's answer:   `"targets": [0,1,2]` You can add multiple columns value here as well

Answer (score 23):

Also, you can group the columns to apply one style to many like so:

```
  columnDefs: [
    { className: 'text-right', targets: [7, 10, 11, 14, 16] },
    { className: 'text-center', targets: [5] },
  ], ...
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also specify a single css class name inside each column object.

In your case:

```
{
    data: 'Status', 
    render: function (data, type, row) {
        switch (data) {
            case 1:
                 return '<div id="circleRed"></div>';
            case 2:
                 return '<div id="circleGreen"></div>';
            case 3:
                 return '<div id="circleOrange"></div>';
        }
    },
    className: "text-center"
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can style that manually

```
$("select_your_table").DataTable({
    ....
    columns: [
        {
            mData: "select_property_from_json",
            render: function (data) {
                return '<span style="display: flex; flex-flow: row nowrap; justify-content: center;">data</span>';
            }
        },
    ],
    ....
});
```

Comment: Thanks! This is the best answer. The problem with the `columnDefs` and `className` approach shown in other answers is that the style is applied on the entire column including header and body cells. It doesn't work if you want to apply the cell styles on the header or body cells separately. Moreover, the base styles of jQuery DataTable cells don't work with Bootstrap themes. Bootstrap seems to override them. In that scenario, this approach suits the best as you don't have to depend on DataTable styles and apply your own styles on the cell content independently.