# Align HTML Table Header in CSS?

Tags: html, css, datatable, html-table

Ok so I am using DataTables JQuery and am trying to get my table data to shift to the left to align with the table header. If I try to use background-align: left, it doesn't work as it only moves the header to the left. I just need the data itself to move to the right to be aligned under the header. Thanks!

```css
table.dataTable {
  width: 100%;
  clear: both;
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

table.dataTable thead th,
table.dataTable tfoot th {
  font-weight: 700;
}

table.dataTable thead th,
table.dataTable thead td {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #111;
  padding: 10px 18px;
}

table.dataTable tfoot th,
table.dataTable tfoot td {
  border-top: 1px solid #111;
  padding: 10px 18px 6px;
}

table.dataTable thead .sorting,
table.dataTable thead .sorting_asc,
table.dataTable thead .sorting_desc,
table.dataTable thead .sorting_asc_disabled,
table.dataTable thead .sorting_desc_disabled {
  cursor: hand;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center right;
}

table.dataTable thead .sorting {
  background-image: url(DataTables-1.10.16/images/sort_both.png);
}

table.dataTable thead .sorting_asc {
  background-image: url(DataTables-1.10.16/images/sort_asc.png);
}

table.dataTable thead .sorting_desc {
  background-image: url(DataTables-1.10.16/images/sort_desc.png);
}

table.dataTable thead .sorting_asc_disabled {
  background-image: url(DataTables- 
 1.10.16/images/sort_asc_disabled.png);
}

table.dataTable thead .sorting_desc_disabled {
  background-image: url(DataTables- 
 1.10.16/images/sort_desc_disabled.png);
}

table.dataTable tbody tr {
  background-color: #fff;
}

table.dataTable tbody tr.selected {
  background-color: #B0BED9;
}

table.dataTable tbody th,
table.dataTable tbody td {
  padding: 8px 10px;
}

table.dataTable.row-border tbody th,
table.dataTable.row-border tbody td,
table.dataTable.display tbody th,
table.dataTable.display tbody td {
  border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
}

table.dataTable.cell-border tbody th,
table.dataTable.cell-border tbody td {
  border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-right: 1px solid #ddd;
}

table.dataTable.cell-border tbody tr th:first- child,
table.dataTable.cell-border tbody tr td:first-child {
  border-left: 1px solid #ddd;
}

table.dataTable.stripe tbody tr.odd,
table.dataTable.display tbody tr.odd {
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
}

table.dataTable.stripe tbody tr.odd.selected,
table.dataTable.display tbody tr.odd.selected {
  background-color: #acbad4;
}

table.dataTable.hover tbody tr:hover,
table.dataTable.display tbody tr:hover {
  background-color: #f6f6f6;
}

table.dataTable.hover tbody tr:hover.selected,
table.dataTable.display tbody tr:hover.selected {
  background-color: #aab7d1;
}

table.dataTable.display tbody tr.odd>.sorting_1,
table.dataTable.order-column.stripe tbody tr.odd>.sorting_1 {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

table.dataTable.display tbody tr.odd>.sorting_2,
table.dataTable.order-column.stripe tbody tr.odd>.sorting_2 {
  background-color: #f3f3f3;
}

table.dataTable.display tbody tr.odd>.sorting_3,
table.dataTable.order-column.stripe tbody tr.odd>.sorting_3 {
  background-color: #F5F5F5;
}

table.dataTable.display tbody tr.odd.selected>.sorting_1,
table.dataTable.order-column.stripe tbody tr.odd.selected>.sorting_1 {
  background-color: #a6b4cd;
}

table.dataTable.display tbody tr.odd.selected>.sorting_2,
table.dataTable.order-column.stripe tbody tr.odd.selected>.sorting_2 {
  background-color: #a8b5cf;
}

table.dataTable.display tbody tr.odd.selected>.sorting_3,
table.dataTable.order-column.stripe tbody tr.odd.selected>.sorting_3 {
  background-color: #a9b7d1;
}

table.dataTable.display tbody tr.even>.sorting_2,
table.dataTable.order-column.stripe tbody tr.even>.sorting_2 {
  background-color: #fcfcfc;
}

table.dataTable.display tbody tr.even>.sorting_3,
table.dataTable.order-column.stripe tbody tr.even>.sorting_3 {
  background-color: #fefefe;
}

table.dataTable.display tbody tr.even.selected>.sorting_2,
table.dataTable.order-column.stripe tbody tr.even.selected>.sorting_2 {
  background-color: #aebcd6;
}

table.dataTable.display tbody tr.even.selected>.sorting_3,
table.dataTable.order-column.stripe tbody tr.even.selected>.sorting_3 {
  background-color: #afbdd8;
}

table.dataTable.display tbody tr:hover>.sorting_1,
table.dataTable.order-column.hover tbody tr:hover>.sorting_1 {
  background-color: #eaeaea;
}

table.dataTable.display tbody tr:hover>.sorting_2,
table.dataTable.order-column.hover tbody tr:hover>.sorting_2 {
  background-color: #ececec;
}

table.dataTable.display tbody tr:hover>.sorting_3,
table.dataTable.order-column.hover tbody tr:hover>.sorting_3 {
  background-color: #efefef;
}

table.dataTable.display tbody tr:hover.selected>.sorting_1,
table.dataTable.order-column.hover tbody tr:hover.selected>.sorting_1 {
  background-color: #a2aec7;
}

table.dataTable.display tbody tr:hover.selected>.sorting_2,
table.dataTable.order-column.hover tbody tr:hover.selected>.sorting_2 {
  background-color: #a3b0c9;
}

table.dataTable.display tbody tr:hover.selected>.sorting_3,
table.dataTable.order-column.hover tbody tr:hover.selected>.sorting_3 {
  background-color: #a5b2cb;
}

table.dataTable.compact thead th,
table.dataTable.compact thead td {
  padding: 4px 17px 4px 4px;
}

table.dataTable,
table.dataTable th,
table.dataTable td {
  box-sizing: content-box;
}

.dataTables_wrapper {
  position: relative;
  clear: both;
  zoom: 1;
}

.dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_length {
  float: left;
}

.dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_filter {
  float: right;
  text-align: right;
}

.dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_filter input {
  margin-left: .5em;
}

.dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_info {
  clear: both;
  float: left;
  padding-top: .755em;
}

.dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_paginate {
  float: right;
  text-align: right;
  padding-top: .25em;
}

.dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_paginate .paginate_button {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: inline-block;
  min-width: 1.5em;
  margin-left: 2px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none!important;
  cursor: hand;
  color: #333!important;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 2px;
  padding: .5em 1em;
}

.dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_paginate .paginate_button.current,
.dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_paginate .paginate_button.current:hover {
  color: #333!important;
  border: 1px solid #979797;
  background-color: #FFF;
}

.dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_paginate .paginate_button.disabled,
.dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_paginate .paginate_button.disabled:hover,
.dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_paginate .paginate_button.disabled:active {
  cursor: default;
  color: #666!important;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  background: transparent;
  box-shadow: none;
}

.dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_paginate .paginate_button:hover {
  color: #FFF!important;
  border: 1px solid #111;
}

.dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_paginate .ellipsis {
  padding: 0 1em;
}

.dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_processing {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  margin-left: -50%;
  margin-top: -25px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  background-color: #FFF;
  background: linear-gradient(toright, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9) 25% rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9) 75% rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 100%;
}

.dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_scroll {
  clear: both;
}

.dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_scroll div.dataTables_scrollBody {
  margin-top: -1px;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}

.dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_scroll div.dataTables_scrollBody>table>thead>tr>th,
.dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_scroll div.dataTables_scrollBody>table>thead>tr>td,
.dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_scroll div.dataTables_scrollBody>table>tbody>tr>th,
.dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_scroll div.dataTables_scrollBody>table>tbody>tr>td {
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_scroll .dataTables_wrapper.no-footer div.dataTables_scrollHead table.dataTable,
.dataTables_wrapper.no-footer div.dataTables_scrollBody>table {
  border-bottom: none;
}

.dataTables_wrapper:after {
  visibility: hidden;
  display: block;
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  height: 0;
}

table.dataTable thead th:active,
table.dataTable thead td:active,
.dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_paginate . .paginate_button:active {
  outline: none;
}

table.dataTable.row-border tbody tr:first-child th,
table.dataTable.row-border tbody tr:first-child td,
table.dataTable.display tbody tr:first-child th,
table.dataTable.display tbody tr:first-child td,
table.dataTable.cell-border tbody tr:first-child th,
table.dataTable.cell-border tbody tr:first-child td {
  border-top: none;
}

table.dataTable.order-column tbody tr>.sorting_1,
table.dataTable.order-column tbody tr>.sorting_2,
table.dataTable.order-column tbody tr>.sorting_3,
table.dataTable.display tbody tr>.sorting_1,
table.dataTable.display tbody tr>.sorting_2,
table.dataTable.display tbody tr>.sorting_3,
table.dataTable.display tbody tr.even>.sorting_1,
table.dataTable.order-column.stripe tbody tr.even>.sorting_1 {
  background-color: #fafafa;
}

table.dataTable.order-column tbody tr.selected>.sorting_1,
table.dataTable.order-column tbody tr.selected>.sorting_2,
table.dataTable.order-column tbody tr.selected>.sorting_3,
table.dataTable.display tbody tr.selected>.sorting_1,
table.dataTable.display tbody tr.selected>.sorting_2,
table.dataTable.display tbody tr.selected>.sorting_3,
table.dataTable.display tbody tr.even.selected>.sorting_1,
table.dataTable.order-column.stripe tbody tr.even.selected>.sorting_1 {
  background-color: #acbad5;
}

table.dataTable.no-footer,
.dataTables_wrapper.no-footer .dataTables_scrollBody {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #111;
}

table.dataTable.nowrap th,
table.dataTable.nowrap td,
table.dataTable th.dt-nowrap,
table.dataTable td.dt-nowrap,
table.dataTable thead th.dt-head-nowrap,
table.dataTable thead td.dt-head- nowrap,
table.dataTable tfoot th.dt-head-nowrap,
table.dataTable tfoot td.dt-head-nowrap,
table.dataTable tbody th.dt-body-n nowrap,
table.dataTable tbody td.dt-body-nowrap {
  white-space: nowrap;
}

table.dataTable.compact tfoot th,
table.dataTable.compact tfoot td,
table.dataTable.compact tbody th,
table.dataTable.compact tbody td {
  padding: 4px;
}

table.dataTable th.dt-left,
table.dataTable td.dt-left,
table.dataTable thead th.dt-head-left,
table.dataTable thead td.dt-head- left,
table.dataTable tfoot th.dt-head-left,
table.dataTable tfoot td.dt-head-left,
table.dataTable tbody th.dt-body-left,
table.dataTable tbody td.dt-body-left {
  text-align: left;
}

table.dataTable th.dt-center,
table.dataTable td.dt- center,
table.dataTable td.dataTables_empty,
table.dataTable thead th.dt-head-center,
table.dataTable thead td.dt-head- center,
table.dataTable tfoot th.dt-head-center,
table.dataTable tfoot td.dt-head-center,
table.dataTable tbody th.dt-body- center,
table.dataTable tbody td.dt-body-center {
  text-align: center;
}

table.dataTable th.dt-right,
table.dataTable td.dt- right,
table.dataTable thead th.dt-head-right,
table.dataTable thead td.dt-head-right,
table.dataTable tfoot th.dt-head- right,
table.dataTable tfoot td.dt-head-right,
table.dataTable tbody th.dt-body-right,
table.dataTable tbody td.dt-body-right {
  text-align: right;
}

table.dataTable th.dt-justify,
table.dataTable td.dt- justify,
table.dataTable thead th.dt-head-justify,
table.dataTable thead td.dt-head-justify,
table.dataTable tfoot th.dt-head- justify,
table.dataTable tfoot td.dt-head-justify,
table.dataTable tbody th.dt-body-justify,
table.dataTable tbody td.dt-body-justify {
  text-align: justify;
}

@media screen and max-width 767px {
  .dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_info,
  .dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_paginate {
    float: none;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_paginate {
    margin-top: .5em;
  }
}

@media screen and max-width 640px {
  .dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_length,
  .dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_filter {
    float: none;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_filter {
    margin-top: .5em;
  }
}

.dataTables_wrapper:after {
  visibility: hidden;
  display: block;
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  height: 0;
}

table.dataTable thead th:active,
table.dataTable thead td:active,
.dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_paginate . .paginate_button:active {
  outline: none;
}

table.dataTable.row-border tbody tr:first-child th,
table.dataTable.row-border tbody tr:first-child td,
table.dataTable.display tbody tr:first-child th,
table.dataTable.display tbody tr:first-child td,
table.dataTable.cell-border tbody tr:first-child th,
table.dataTable.cell-border tbody tr:first-child td {
  border-top: none;
}

table.dataTable.order-column tbody tr>.sorting_1,
table.dataTable.order-column tbody tr>.sorting_2,
table.dataTable.order-column tbody tr>.sorting_3,
table.dataTable.display tbody tr>.sorting_1,
table.dataTable.display tbody tr>.sorting_2,
table.dataTable.display tbody tr>.sorting_3,
table.dataTable.display tbody tr.even>.sorting_1,
table.dataTable.order-column.stripe tbody tr.even>.sorting_1 {
  background-color: #fafafa;
}

table.dataTable.order-column tbody tr.selected>.sorting_1,
table.dataTable.order-column tbody tr.selected>.sorting_2,
table.dataTable.order-column tbody tr.selected>.sorting_3,
table.dataTable.display tbody tr.selected>.sorting_1,
table.dataTable.display tbody tr.selected>.sorting_2,
table.dataTable.display tbody tr.selected>.sorting_3,
table.dataTable.display tbody tr.even.selected>.sorting_1,
table.dataTable.order-column.stripe tbody tr.even.selected>.sorting_1 {
  background-color: #acbad5;
}

table.dataTable.no-footer,
.dataTables_wrapper.no-footer .dataTables_scrollBody {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #111;
}

table.dataTable.nowrap th,
table.dataTable.nowrap td,
table.dataTable th.dt-nowrap,
table.dataTable td.dt-nowrap,
table.dataTable thead th.dt-head-nowrap,
table.dataTable thead td.dt-head- nowrap,
table.dataTable tfoot th.dt-head-nowrap,
table.dataTable tfoot td.dt-head-nowrap,
table.dataTable tbody th.dt-body-n nowrap,
table.dataTable tbody td.dt-body-nowrap {
  white-space: nowrap;
}

table.dataTable.compact tfoot th,
table.dataTable.compact tfoot td,
table.dataTable.compact tbody th,
table.dataTable.compact tbody td {
  padding: 4px;
}

table.dataTable th.dt-left,
table.dataTable td.dt-left,
table.dataTable thead th.dt-head-left,
table.dataTable thead td.dt-head- left,
table.dataTable tfoot th.dt-head-left,
table.dataTable tfoot td.dt-head-left,
table.dataTable tbody th.dt-body-left,
table.dataTable tbody td.dt-body-left {
  text-align: left;
}

table.dataTable th.dt-center,
table.dataTable td.dt- center,
table.dataTable td.dataTables_empty,
table.dataTable thead th.dt-head-center,
table.dataTable thead td.dt-head- center,
table.dataTable tfoot th.dt-head-center,
table.dataTable tfoot td.dt-head-center,
table.dataTable tbody th.dt-body- center,
table.dataTable tbody td.dt-body-center {
  text-align: center;
}

table.dataTable th.dt-right,
table.dataTable td.dt- right,
table.dataTable thead th.dt-head-right,
table.dataTable thead td.dt-head-right,
table.dataTable tfoot th.dt-head- right,
table.dataTable tfoot td.dt-head-right,
table.dataTable tbody th.dt-body-right,
table.dataTable tbody td.dt-body-right {
  text-align: right;
}

table.dataTable th.dt-justify,
table.dataTable td.dt- justify,
table.dataTable thead th.dt-head-justify,
table.dataTable thead td.dt-head-justify,
table.dataTable tfoot th.dt-head- justify,
table.dataTable tfoot td.dt-head-justify,
table.dataTable tbody th.dt-body-justify,
table.dataTable tbody td.dt-body-justify {
  text-align: justify;
}

@media screen and max-width 767px {
  .dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_info,
  .dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_paginate {
    float: none;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_paginate {
    margin-top: .5em;
  }
}

@media screen and max-width 640px {
  .dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_length,
  .dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_filter {
    float: none;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_filter {
    margin-top: .5em;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>CryptoCost.live</title>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/
    jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">
  </script>
  <!--JQuery online link-->
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/dt- 
     1.10.16/datatables.min.js"></script>
  <!--JS online link-->
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#mytable').DataTable();
    });
  </script>

  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Varela" rel="stylesheet">
  <!--font link-->
  <link href="style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
  <!--CSS 
    file link-->
  <script src="script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <!-- JS 
    file link-->
</head>

<body>
  <header id="top">
    <!--id "top" for a "return to top of page" button-->
    <h1>
      <!--header-->
      CryptoCost.live<img src="" width="25">
      <font size="4"><span class="Priceandmarketcap">Live 
    Cryptocurrency Prices & Market Capitalization</span></font>
      <font size="2"><span class="SearchCoinsHead">Search Coins: 
    <font><input type="text" id="search" class="light-table-filter" 
    placeholder="BTC.."></font></span></font>
    </h1>
  </header>

  <br>
  <!--vertical whitespace-->



  <table id="mytable" class="display" style="width:100%">
    <thead>
      <!--start of table header-->
      <tr>
        <th>#</th>
        <th>Coins</th>
        <th>Price</th>
        <th>24H Change</th>
        <th>24H Volume</th>
        <th>Market Cap</th>
        <th>Circulating Coin Supply</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <!--end of table header-->
    <tbody>
      <!--start of table body-->
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>
          <a href="BTCprice.html"> <img src="\" width="15"> BTC
          </a>
        </td>
        <td><big>$7000</big></td>
        <!--price-->
        <td><big>-15%</big></td>
        <!--24H % Change-->
        <td><big>30,284 BTC</big></td>
        <!--24H Volume-->
        <td><big>$117,727,059,656</big></td>
        <!--Market Cap-->
        <td><big>16,946,875 BTC</big></td>
        <!--Circulating Coin Supply-->
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>
          <a href="ETHprice.html"> <img src="" width="12"> ETH </a>
        </td>
        <td><big>$400</big></td>
        <td><big>+32%</big></td>
        <td><big>98,497,625 ETH</big></td>
        <td><big>$37,143,553,062</big></td>
        <td><big>98,497,625 ETH</big></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>
          <a href="LTCprice.html"> <img src="https://8356- 
    presscdn-0-69-pagely.netdna-ssl.com/wp- 
    content/uploads/2017/06/Litecoin.png" width="15"> LTC </a>
        </td>
        <td><big>$120</big></td>
        <td><big>-40%</big></td>
        <td><big>55,849,820 LTC</big></td>
        <td><big>$6,269,309,798</big></td>
        <td><big>55,849,820 LTC</big></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    <!--end of table body-->
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Try using text-align

Comment: Why don't you align the whole table or row to the left or right wherever you need it? or as above use text-align instead but put it on the table class.

Comment: dupe. https://stackoverflow.com/q/45446910/483257

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery Datatables align center 1 column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45446910/jquery-datatables-align-center-1-column)